# Is it possible for a multiple critical point of a polynomial $p$ not to be a multiple zero of $p(z)+c$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $p$ be a univariate polynomial and $p'$ its derivative. Due to the product rule, it's clear that if some number is a multiple zero of $p$, it will be a zero of $p'$ as well. But is it possible for $p$ to have a critical point $a$ of order $m>1$ where $a$ is not a zero of multiplicity at least $m$ of $p(z) + c$, for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$? If not, how would you show it? I'm guessing there's some way with integration by parts, but it's escaping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ir $a$ is a zero of order $m$ of $p’(z)$, then it is a zero of order $m+1$ of $p(z)-p(a)$.

Comment: Typo; $a$ is a zero of $p’$.

Comment: I would still like to see it shown formally. Thank you, though.

Comment: What do you mean by _formally_?